# Restore site collection using powershell : Getting not found error

Tags: powershell, restore

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http:/snk145:60000/ -Path "D:/MS.bak"
```

I am trying to restore a site collection (SharePoint 2010) to other from a backup file,

```
The term 'Restore-SPSite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:15
+ Restore-SPSite <<<<  -Identity http:/snk145:60000/ -Path "D:/MS.bak"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Restore-SPSite:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What Should I do?

**UPDATE**

As Alex said, got the command worked, however getting another error as follows

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http:/snk145:60000/ -Path "D:/MS.bak"

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing operation "Restore-SPSite" on Target "http:/son1834:60000/".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

```
Restore-SPSite : Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed.
At line:1 char:15
+ Restore-SPSite <<<<  -Identity http:/snk145:60000/ -Path "D:/MS.bak"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:SPCmdletRestoreSite) [Restore-SPSite], U
   riFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreSite
```

What next?

Comment: Is it because of the forward slash? Replace it with backslash in the path -'D:\MS.bak' and retry.

Comment: No deepu it was a problem that Alex suggested, please look at the question for another error

Comment: Try to use double slash -Identity http:**//**snk145:60000/

Comment: Hi Jithu - check this post detailing how powershell scripts are executed - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/sharepoint2010setup/thread/37dad645-a413-43de-9990-ab1579e1ba6c

Comment: Thank you Deepu for the link!! Definitely I can avoid some future errors !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` command before your script.

Comment: Hi Alex That did the trick however now I am getting another error I will update the question to include it !!

Comment: Got it - http://

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you are using the Windows PowerShell instead of the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell. I would suggest you to run the CMDLet from the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell from the server where SharePoint 2010 is installed.

Check also the path you have entered - 'D:/MS.bak' . Shouldn't that be 'D:\MS.bak' with a backslash?